# React Native works with a real device but not with an android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, metro-bundler, react-native-cli

- OS: **Linux Ubuntu**
- CLI or Expo: **CLI**
- RN Version: **0.70.6**

I start my React Native project with the following commands:

- `yarn start`
- `yarn react-native run-android`

It works when a real device connected to my PC and the project starts on my device. But it does not work with an Android Emulator.

When I try with an emulator:

- `yarn start` command shows usual outputs. No error, nothing. Seems to work correctly
- `yarn react-native run-android` also same. Build successful. No error or warning.
- `adb devices` command shows my emulator correctly.

But emulator does not start my project. I can see my project icon on the emulator. When I double click to my project, I just see a blank screen for one second or less and it closed again.

When i try to reload metro using `r` command on terminal it says no apps connected.

I think the emulator builds the app but not connect to metro properly. I don't know why. I cannot see any error or warning messages.

I tried `./gradlew clean` and delete node_modules and install but it didn't work.
I also tried `yarn start --port 8081` but it also didn't work.

**EDIT**: For testing purpose, I created a new project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject' and it works on the emulator. So I think the problem is only about the other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
In my case it was because of Flipper version. When I changed it from *0.125* to *0.144* my project started on an android emulator properly.

Here is the link where i found the solution:
[react-native-issue-in-github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34363)